# asp.net shopping cart update quantity in cookie

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, cookies, shopping-cart

in shopping cart web page i have this list view to show items in cart:

```
 <asp:ListView ID="List" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID">


          <table class="tbl">
                    <tr>
                      <td class="one">
                        <h4><%# Eval("ID")%></h4>
                      </td>
                      <td class="two">
                         <h4><%# Eval("Name")%></h4>
                      </td>
                      <td class="fone"><%# Eval("Total")%></td>

                      <td>
                          <asp:DropDownList runat="server" CssClass='drop' SelectedValue='<%# Eval("Qty")%>'>
                          <asp:ListItem value="1">1</asp:ListItem>
                          <asp:ListItem value="2">2</asp:ListItem>
                          <asp:ListItem value="3">3</asp:ListItem>
                          <asp:ListItem value="4">4</asp:ListItem>
                         </asp:DropDownList>
                      </td> 

                      <td class="ffour"><%# Eval("Price")%></td>
                    </tr>

            </table>
```

items retrieve from cookie .when user add item to cart, item added to this listview .
i have written jquery code to, when user change quantity of one item , totalprice automatically has been changed .

```
 $('.drop').on('change', function () {
               var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
               var price = $(tr).find('.ffour').html();
               $(tr).find('.fone').html(price * $(this).val());
           });
```

how to do when user change quantity , qty in cookie changes too?for example , when user change quantity of first row from 1 to 2 , in website cookie , qty changes from 1 to 2 .

name of cookie is 'SiteCookie' . and has Qty for quantity of products.

Comment: please show where u have used cookies?

Comment: in asp.net code-behind i read cookie with HttpCookie currentCookie = Request.Cookies["SiteCookie"];

Comment: then load products in cookie to ArrayList , and then fill Listview with ArrayList . All things is good and work , but when user change quantity of one product for example 1 to 2 , i want to store this changes to cookie . how?

Comment: Instead of that u can take cookies in jqueries as well .. and i think that will be useful in your case

Comment: possible duplicate of [change quantity of item in shopping cart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22126990/change-quantity-of-item-in-shopping-cart)

Comment: Please don't duplicate questions.

Answer (score 0):

First of all Take this [js for Cookies](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/blob/master/jquery.cookie.js) and then

```
       $('.drop').on('change', function () {
           $.cookie("qty",$(this).closest('tr'))
           var price = $(tr).find('.ffour').html();
           $(tr).find('.fone').html(price * $.cookie("qty"));
       });
```

On page load as well u can call cookie... if cookie has value then perform this

```
      $(tr).find('.fone').html(price * $.cookie("qty"));
```

Comment: can you invite me to chat? i explain what i want.

Comment: yah sure.. come over [this group](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43899/dont-rely-on-us) @user3234297